# Progressbar in ActionBar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am working with an app which will load a website Inside the app .Now i want to add a ProgressBar in action bar without swipe up to repress feature.

**Like that**

[image]

I am using **Fragment** in my app.

**WebviewFragment**

```
public class WebviewFragment extends Fragment {

    WebView webView;
    String newslink;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview, container, false);

        newslink = getArguments().getString("LINK");


        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(newslink);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        return view;

    }


}
```

**fragment_webview.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >




        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Any **solution** for me ?

Comment: user requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); read more http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(boolean)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want add progress to actionbar call this method before setlayout

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

**UPDATE** where should request window feature

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     .... // other code goes here 
       }
```

and call this method when you want run it

**EDIT in fragment** you can add `getActivity()` before `requestWindowFeature`  to be `getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);`

```
 setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); // turn progress on

     setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); // turn progress off
```

hope this work , my recommendation to use toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/material_green_500"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateTint="#795548"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

> Why I recommended toolbar with ProgressBar ?

for two reasons , **First** [setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(boolean)) deprecated.

**Second** easy to use just set `setVisibility` method  to make it visible call `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
to hide view call `setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)` Where this code will be placed in webviewFragment ? **Error is** - _requestFeature() must be called before adding content_

Comment: I update my answer . please read my recommendation happy coding

Comment: I am using fragment sir .