# How do you add a clickable textview to an action bar in Android?

Tags: android, menu, textview, android-actionbar

I want to have a textview that says "Edit" aligned to the right of an action bar but don't know to implement it. Should it be in a menu resource? If so, I want to be able to customize the colour of it. Otherwise, should I put it within the toolbar xml itself?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a toolbar instead, it's a viewgroup like any other viewgroup, then you can put the TextView inside it, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35548546/3578585) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a custom implementation of action bar only. You can do something like this if you're not using toolbar.

```
try {

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_toolbar);
        textView_actionBar = (TextView)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_textView","id",getPackageName()));
        textView_actionBar.setText("Your_title");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Define the textView's clicklistener as per need.

In custom_toolbar.xml just put an TextView and align it to right end. The layout background set as per your choice.

Comment: please accept the answers that provide you the solution to your problem